# Adding items from ComboBox to Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, datagrid, combobox

I need to insert items from my `ComboBox` to my `Datagrid` when I click on an item in my combobox(**SelectionChanged** event).

I load the data from a WCF application into the comboboxes with the following method:

```
private async Task LoadItems(TruckServiceClient TSC, QuoteOptionType type, ComboBox combobox)
{
    List<DisplayItems> displayItems = new List<DisplayItems>();
    foreach (var item in await TSC.GetQuoteOptionListAsync(type))
        displayItems.Add(new DisplayItems { Id = item.Key, Name = item.Value });
    combobox.ItemsSource = (displayItems.ToArray());
}
```

and then I sort which data goes where in my *WindowLoaded* event:

```
private async void QuoteWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.BodyType, cmbBodyType);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.Chassis, cmbChassisCab);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.PaintColor, cmbPaint);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.DropSide, cmbDropsideHeight);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.Floor, cmbFloor);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.RearDropSide, cmbRearDropsideHeight);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.Extras, cmbAddExtras);
    }
}
```

What I am desperate to know is how would I go about to display the item that I just clicked on(in the combobox) to be added to the datagrid?

I have tried the following coding that I found on the internet, but I do not even know where to start to change the coding from what it is below to how I need it to work with my current way of loading the items into the comboboxes.

```
    Extras ex = (Extras)cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem;
    List<Extra> items = new List<Extra> { E };

    items.Where(item => item != null).ToList().ForEach(i =>
    {
        dgAddExtras.Items.Add(i);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the `SelectiongChanged` event, either on XAML or on your Loaded method. And then in the event handler simply retrieve the selected item and add it to the DataGrid:

```
private async void QuoteWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.BodyType, cmbBodyType);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.Chassis, cmbChassisCab);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.PaintColor, cmbPaint);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.DropSide, cmbDropsideHeight);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.Floor, cmbFloor);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.RearDropSide, cmbRearDropsideHeight);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.Extras, cmbAddExtras);
    }

    combAddExtras.SelectionChanged += cmbAddExtras_SelectionChanged;
}

private void cmbAddExtras_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem;

    if (item != null)
        dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**EDIT** - If you want to remove the item from the Combo:

```
private void cmbAddExtras_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem;

    if (item != null)
    {
        dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
        cmbAddExtras.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

If you don't wanna remove it from the Combo, but wanna check it isn't already in the DataGrid:

```
private void cmbAddExtras_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem;

    if (item != null && !dgAddExtras.Items.Contains(item))
        dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! :) The last example of coding I gave doesn't contain any real classes that I use. I am struggling to get a working method for adding the items from the QuoteWindow_Loaded method to the datagrid. The line here: `await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.Extras, cmbAddExtras);` is where I add the items to the combobox

Comment: You can't add the items to the DataGrid from the `QuoteWindow_Loaded` method, since you want them to be added only when the user selects them from the Combo. Isn't that right? To get that behavior you just need to subscribe to the Combo's `SelectionChanged` event and copy my code to the event handler. If the `SelectedItem` property doesn't return an `Extras` object, then just go with `object`. You'll have to deal with how to show the data in the DataGrid later, though, so you better know which classes you're dealing with.

Comment: Edited. Without knowing what the `Loaditems` method does, without knowing the classes you're working with, and without seeing your XAML, that's the best I can do. Maybe you could explain why you're struggling, what problems are you encountering?

Comment: Thank you so very much almulo! Your coding and explenations helped me alot. I tried to over-complicate things. Simple is much better.